# Inlining this function or not?

Tags: c++, whitespace, inline, strcmp

I'm supposed to implement a function which compares two strings simliar so `strcmp` but ignoring whitespace characters, so

```
strcmpignorews("abc   ", " a b c")
```

should give the same result.

Here's my implementation:

```
namespace {
    void SkipWhitespace(const char *&s) {
        for (; std::isspace(*s, std::locale::classic); ++s);
    }
}

int strcmpignorews(const char *s1, const char *s2) {
    for (; *s1 != '\0' && *s2 != '\0'; ++s1, ++s2) {
        SkipWhitespace(s1);
        SkipWhitespace(s2);

        if (*s1 != *s2) {
            break;
        }
    }

    return (*s1 < *s2) ? -1 : ((*s1 == *s2) ? 0 : 1);
}
```

Now, the question is, would it make sense to inline the SkipWhitespace function? I think I've read somewhere that `inline` should not be used for functions which contain loops or switches but I can't remember where and why.

Comment: @HelperMethod: You can replace all the spaces in the string and then compare that will make your code neat and simple.

Comment: @dhinesh: Definitely **not**. What use is a function that destroys its arguments when it does not have to?

Comment: @Jon: You can always copy the arguments to some temporary variables, which will not destroy the arguments.

Comment: @dhinesh: You can also copy the arguments 10 times and only use the 10th copy. But there's no reason to.

Comment: @Helper Method: not related to your question, but you probably want to check for 0 or '\0', not '0' as end of string

Comment: @dhinesh - what if one of the incoming parameters is, for example, a 2-gigabyte memory mapped file on a 32-bit system. Would you still be happy copying it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Historically, Inline has been an indication to the compiler that it should insert the function body into the call site.  However, that is no longer a meaningful annotation.  Modern compilers will inline a function or not regardless of the presence or absence of `inline` qualification.

To emphasize, whether compiler will perform inline optimization is *completely out of your hands*.

In modern use, inline has only one function.  It can be used to get the linker to ignore multiple symbols, as when a function is defined in multiple compilation units.  This technique can be used to break circular dependencies.  Use inline for no other purpose.

Comment: +1 Thx for the nice explanation. I was always wondering why I should use inline when e.g. `gcc` does it anyway (at least with optimisation lvl 3).

Comment: Very nice answer. I would also add that since the OP is still learning C++, they should learn to *never, ever try to optimize "by eye"* while there's still time.

Comment: There is one thing to add to your answer - there are some options to the compiler to force it not to inline functions not to market as `inline`.

Comment: @Vlad: Most compilers have specific options that alter the behavior of the inline optimizer, but they are not universal from compiler to compiler.  My answer applies equally to all compilers.

Comment: "whether compiler will perform inline optimization is completely out of your hands".  This is not accurate. If you don't inline a function the the compiler is likely not able to inline it anywhere outside the compilation unit that defines it. Marking a function is inline is not only a suggestion but also an _allowance_ for the compiler to inline the function in any compilation unit.

Comment: @wilhelmtell: Probably not true on most modern compilers. Inter translation unit inlining is a relatively common optimization. Humans are absolutely usless at deciding when to optimize let the compiler do its job it is much better than you.

Comment: @MartinYork Can you give me references for that? For what I know C++ compilers will commonly compile compilation units in a stateless manner. Only the linker sees stuff across compilation units, but the linker is relatively dumb and its past the stage of optimization.

Comment: @MartinYork Also, I think I'm familiar with being careful with inline. I think I made it clear in my answer.

Comment: @wilhelmtell: Doubting Tomas aye. [gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) Search for `-flto`

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't say it *shouldn't* be used under those circumstances but the act of inlining code will have a larger benefit if the code is relatively quick.

That's because inlining gets rid of the overhead of a function call. If a function call and return takes one second but the code you're inlining takes ten minutes, you're not going to see a huge improvement. But, if the code you're inlining also takes one second, you'll basically double its performance.

Just keep in mind that `inline` is a *suggestion* to the compiler, one it can freely ignore if it figures out you're wrong or even if it's just being obnoxious. I rarely use it and rarely find a need for it, relegating it to the same category as `auto` and `register` (at least in C).

Comment: +1 This explanation makes much more sense than what I've read so far. Most books say that you should inline functions if they are less than / equal 10 lines long which is a bad hint imho.

Comment: Yes, there's little point inlining the one-line function `void x(void) { sleep (10000000); }`. On the other hand, a hundred-line function that only takes 0.00000001 seconds may be a candidate. But my advice stands, give it a miss as a newcomer, let the compiler decide. Once you're more advanced and know how to profile code, change it if you know both (1) its performance is a problem; and (2) inlining will improve that. Measure, don't guess.

Comment: I want to emphasize something super important for those working on applications where performance is critical. Inlining, even when it does not introduce code bloat (inlining a single line accessor), can have terrible effects on performance. It can cause the compiler to equally attempt to optimize commonly executed code paths with not so commonly executed ones. Sometimes you want the overhead and bloat of a separate function and call for a more rarely executed code path because it'll help the compiler optimize the functions that are commonly executed.

Comment: In other words, code bloat as a result of not inlining can actually be helpful to the optimizing compiler. What optimizing compilers don't know is what runtime conditions are the most common; only the human programmer can know that, and we're not coding in assembly. The best thing you can do to help your compiler work is not inline those rarely executed paths and structure your code in a way such that the branch conditions to execute these less commonly executed paths are contained in the outer function. if (some_rare_condition) non_inlined_rare_function();

Answer (score 3):

The `inline` keyword has always been a mere suggestion for the compiler. That means that if the compiler so chooses then it may ignore the suggestion. On top of that, if the compiler can inline a function it may inline the function even if you didn't ask it to do so.

That said, in order for the compiler to inline a function it must know the function's body. If the function is defined in a separate compilation unit then the compiler probably doesn't know the function's definition outside that compilation unit. In this case the compiler can only inline the function in callers within the compilation unit that defines the function. So the point to take from that is that if you want to *allow* the compiler to inline a function then you must define the function in the class definition or add the `inline` keyword and define it in the header. Inline functions don't violate the [ODR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule).

Another consideration you should make is that because inline functions must reside in a header, and because headers are typically included by a number of compilation units, inline functions increase static coupling. That means that changing the definition of an inline function will cause a cascade in compilation through all dependent compilation units. This is important: a function's *definition* is not supposed to be part of the interface, but inline functions force this coupling.

For that last point alone, at the end, I'd say **never** inline a function. That is, until you are irritated enough by the runtime performance of your application or library, at which point you should run your profiler to see if any particular functions would boost performance inlined. Inline functions can also reduce the executable's size if inlining them results in a smaller object code than code necessary for generating a function call, but that's less a significant decision factor in most but few (embedded?) contexts.

The profiler can tell you that a particular function can boost performance if it's inlined, but it can't tell you if a particular inlined function can boost performance (size, runtime, development, ...) if it's un-inlined.

Answer (score 3):

In general, **Profile before inlining**.

Inlining is always a suggestion to the compiler.  It retains the right to ignore you or agree with you.  It may be inlining other parts of your code without your permission anyway.

If you don't mind extra typing, here are some guidelines for declaring a method or function as inline:

1. The content of the method uses less
   than or equal to the instruction
   cycles for calling, initializing,
   cleaning up and returning from the
   method.
2. The method has no jumps, or branches
   to other methods.
3. The method has no loops (nowadays,
   small loops can fit into a
   processor's cache).
4. The method only uses methods that
   are inlined or can be inlined, this
   includes library functions.
5. You're converting a macro
   (`#define`).
6. The method passes the above tests
   (except 5), and is thoroughly
   tested.  (Can you say rebuild all
   dependencies because you changed a
   header?)

My style is to inline class getters & setters.  Any code that is volatile (either not working or subject to change) or is complex will not be inlined.

Answer (score 2):

In the context, there is no harm and possibly some good in using `inline`.

There are limits on the complexity of a function that the compiler will inline; functions with complex loops or switches are more likely to reach that limit than functions without.  So, what you read isn't all wrong; it just needs to be qualified.

Stylistically, I'd use a `while` loop in place of your `for` loop:

```
while (isspace(*s, std::locale::classic))
    ++s;
```

This also fixes the bug in your code which only skips characters that are not white space characters.  (*The bug was fixed while this answer was typed!*)

Comment: The bugs was a typo. Fixed it.